# How can I search an array of arrays comparing against each first element?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using either vanilla JavaScript or Lodash, how can I search an array of arrays comparing against the first element of each child array and return the second element of the matched array?

For example, if I have an array of arrays like this:

```
[['22','222'], ['23','223'], ['24','224']]
```

And I have an array of the first elements I want to search with:

```
['22','23','24']
```

For each element in the array of first elements, I want to find its matching second element from the original array ('222','223' or '224' respectively).

I get this data from an API, so I cannot change the format.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: If you know how to write a `for` loop, how to access an array member by index, and how to do an equality comparison, you know how to do this. So which part do you not know?

Comment: @Alexander I want to pick the second element of the array by matching the first element. So for example by saying `find the array which have the first element set to `23` and give it's second element` i should get `223`

Comment: @squint The problem is, I have the first elements (in this case 22,23,24) in an array... I loop through that and try to get the second elements by matching. Adding another loop inside that might become ugly right? Hope we can have a better solution.

Comment: Loops aren't required to get an element. There's no need for a second loop, because you already know that you want to compare the value at index `0` and if it matches, retrieve the value at index `1`.

Comment: Don't "update" your question. No-one is interesting in the sequence of edits you made. If you want to edit your question, just edit it. In this case, through, your update is inconsistent with the initial description of the problem, which remains in your question. PS. If you just want to find a value in the an array, use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution in plain Javascript, with a function which utilized [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var array = [['22', '222'], ['23', '223'], ['24', '224']];

function getValue(v) {
    var r;
    array.some(function (a) {
        if (a[0] === v) {
            r = a[1];
            return true;
        }
    });
    return r;
}

document.write(getValue(0) + '<br>'); // undefined
document.write(getValue('23'));       // '223'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var condition = ['22', '23', '24'];
var data = [
  ['22','222'], 
  ['23','223'], 
  ['24','224'],
  ['25','225'],
  ['26','226']
];

var result = data.filter(function (el) {
  return condition.indexOf(el[0]) >= 0;
}).map(function (el) {
  return el[1];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how many times you need to search this "matrix", but if you need to do it more than once, I think you should adapt the format yourself, this way:

```
var arr = [['22','222'], ['23','223'], ['24','224']];
var dict = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    dict[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
}
```

A single search could cost you as this format-change action, and after you do it - any of the retrievals you're about to do will be efficient.

Comment: And since the OP seems to be open to using lodash, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array checking to see if the first element of the current array item is the same as the search term, returnin the second element if a match is found.

This will only return the first matching element found (or undefined if no match was found), but it seems that is what you're looking for and if so, this is much more efficient than most of the other answers.

```js
var arr = [['22','222'], ['23','223'], ['24','224']];

function search(arr, term) {
    for(var i in arr) if(arr[i][0] === term) return arr[i][1];
}

// For demo purposes only
function demo(key) { document.write(key + ' => ' + search(arr, key) + '<br>'); }           
var find = ['22','23','24','25'];
for(var i in find) demo(find[i]);
```

Comment: In terms of API design, I'd rather return undefined if not found.

Comment: @torazaburo I've updated my example with that in mine. I like your ES6 example.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript solution:

```js
var array = [['22', '222'], ['23', '223'], ['24', '224']];

var result;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i][0] == '23') { // compare the first element with '23'
        result = array[i][1]; // the second element
        break;
    }
}

// Demo
if(typeof result !== 'undefined') { // result was found
    document.writeln(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If available, `Array#find` makes it straightforward:

```
arr.find(sub => sub[0]==='23')[1]
```

To handle case of not found (will return undefined):

```
(arr.find(sub => sub[0] === '23') || []) [1]
```